# How to add android expansion files using Qt

Tags: android, qt, google-play, qml, apk-expansion-files

I am currently developing an Android app using Qt / QML and my app will be a lot larger than the 50 MB Google Play Store limit due to media files that are to be bundled, so I have to use extension files. After some searching I found on a [page](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt-contributors-summit-2013-Qt_Android_Planning_CS_2013) a line saying that Qt resource system can help make .obb extension files:

"For large resources that do not fit into the Google Play store 50 MB limit, qrc can generate rcc files that can be put in obb"

but I can not find any information on how to do this or how to access those files from my code.

EDIT:
I have made an .rcc file using Qt. Trying to convert it to .obb now. Anyone done this using the jobb tool?

I was also thinking that I could just upload the .rcc file directly as Google Play accepts any file format for expansion files, but then I would not be able to get it encrypted.. but how could I access the .rcc file? Do I have to write some Java code or could I get it to work from Qt C++/QML?

EDIT:
I figured it out. I created an external binary resource file using the rcc tool available in Qt command prompt. Using QResource class I can load the external binary resource file and access it as it was a normal qrc resource file.

Comment: If you have figured it out, please put as answer and accept it so this doesn't show up on the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue with expansion files and solved it. Although I did not cover any encryption issues.

Please consult the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31911151/3155461