# How can I get `/sdcard` path in android using Qt APIs

Tags: android, qt, android-sdcard, qapplication

I am using a `QtApp` on android. My `QtApp` has a `AndroidManifest.xml` as well where I can declare android permissions that my app needs.

My app is well able to save anything into the private directory of the app which is `/data/user/0/com.something.something.myapp/files/`.

**Now**, I want to be able to create & save files into `/sdcard/Download/` folder of my android device. But I am unable to save it anything into the `/sdcard/Download/` !!

I have the following permissions declared in Manifest as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What am I missing here? I do the following call get application directory on android

```
QString app_private_location = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
```

**Question:** Is there some `Qt API` to get the `/sdcard` path in android?
Or do I have to rely on android native code for this?  I tried passing `/sdcard/Download/` manually but does not help.

Comment: On native android it is called getExternalStorage() try to find it

Comment: I know that android native call `getExternalStorage` fetches `/sdcard`. I am looking for an API is `Qt` which could give me the same. My app is a Qt with C++ app

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the path by using [JNI](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) in the Qt Android Extras module. You can find an example of what you want in this post:

[How to get the android <shared-storage> path from Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910050/how-to-get-the-android-shared-storage-path-from-qt)